# Visualizing Graph-only with TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to view my network graph with tensor board. I read the page https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard 
My question is : can I visualize the graph without creating the summaries and the FileWriter ?

Answer (score 3):

Following  http://ischlag.github.io/2016/06/04/how-to-use-tensorboard/ I added the following code after the session object was created:

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/tensorflow/", sess.graph)
```

Then I used the command in the blog:
    tensorboard --logdir=run1:/tmp/tensorflow/ --port 6006

TensorBoard gives you back the page you should open to visualize the graph:
"TensorBoard 0.1.6 at http://page:6006"